# Delete not working in Hibernate / Spring Data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Let's say that I have:

```
class Car {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wheel", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Wheel> wheels;

}

class Wheel {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Car car

}
```

I have this code (spring data, wheelRepository extends CrudRepository) to delete a Wheel:

```
wheelRepository.delete(wheel);
```

The code does not delete the wheel and does not throw any exception.
Looking at the sql log, there is no "delete" statement.

I finally found a the problem: I have a car with a wheel set containing the wheel.

Doing this will solve the issue:

```
car.getWheels().remove(wheel);
wheelRepository.delete(wheel);
```

But is it possible to avoid the first line: when I delete a wheel, I want the wheel to be removed from its car automatically?

Another question: is it possible by default to throw an exception instead of having a "silently non-delete"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not quite possible. When you call `wheelRepository.delete(wheel)` you essentially ask to remove the wheel from the database. But this cannot remove an instance `wheel` from all other places in your running application where this instance is now referenced. Such as `car.wheels`. So this instance will continue to live. Thus, it cannot be removed from the database. If you want to remove a `wheel` you have first to remove it from all `cars` that use that `wheel`. Exactly like in real life :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `wheels` field like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wheel", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
Set<Wheel> wheels;
```

This will ensure that when you remove the `Wheel` entity the `Car` entities that became orphans because of it will get removed as well.

Comment: But I don't want to remove the car, just want to remove one wheel :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete `Wheel` which contains `Car`

But for `Car` you have not specified `CascadeType`.

So while deleting `Wheel` it does ntg to `Car`.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Add this to Car inside Wheel and try.